# Tube amplifier with buzz

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, audio, speakers, vacuum-tube

I built a tube (UK: valve) amplifier but it has one problem. When I turn it on, it starts buzzing at 150 Hz but only if I connect the audio output transformer.

If I directly connect the speaker to the plate it works pretty well, but it's not powerful.

Changing the transformer or the capacitor's value changes the frequency of the buzz.

How can I keep the transformer in circuit but get rid of the buzz?

Here is the schematic:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you’ve made an audio oscillator. Is it only yhe output stage oscillating? What tube are you using with a plate voltage of only 24V? And the output transformer impedance?

Comment: You didn't say which capacitor value changes the buzz, but the cathode bias bypass capacitor is orders of magnitude too small. (And I see no supply decoupling)

Comment: As the comments say, we need a bit more information. What tubes are you using? What is the plate voltage? Which capacitor have you changed?

Comment: Is this related to power supply noise and/or orientation of transformer windings for inductive crosstalk or phase polarity of output current for conductive ground noise positive feedback

Comment: 47uF is enough to stabilise the cathode for all the audible frequencies that the human ear can detect in a typical EL84 or 6BQ5 single pentode output stage. 470nF is crazy small.

Comment: Thanks for all support! I am using an ECC82 double triode, and a PL84 pentode (PL84 is salvaged from a TV, can this be an issue?). My power supply is a bunch of 9v batteries which make a higher voltage, so it cannot be noise from the power supply. Also, even if I put my finger across the anode resistors (dropping its resistance) it changes the frequency of the buzz.

Comment: If i connect +24v to the grid of the second tube through a very large resistor, the buzzing frequency increases.

Comment: @GeorgeChita - the ECC84 has a standard 6.3 volt heater, and the PL84 is a series-heater chain 0.3A TV type valve/tube with a heater voltage of 15 volts. How are you heating them? Both usually have an anode voltage over 150 volts. Also I can't help thinking that getting HT ('B+') supply from a stack of dry cells is going to be rather high impedance and make for instability. Where did you get this circuit? Off some guy on Youtube? Note the PL84 is not a 'low-voltage EL84'. It is more like an EL86.

Comment: I made this circuit once before and it worked, but instead of PL84 I used a 6P3S. I just have the filaments in series powered from 21.3 volts. I indeed got the diagram from youtube, from Usagi Electric, but as I mentioned previously , It does work.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the ECC82 nor the PL84 you say you're using are rated to operate at such a low B+ as the 24V you show in the diagram.  While it's not impossible to coax the ECC82 into almost functioning at a B+ of tens of volts, it does require deliberate and non-trivial work - e.g., just reducing the anode resistors as shown isn't near enough to get an ECC82 to bias properly at 24V B+.  And after you do all that non-trivial work, you'll likely be disappointed in the results.
You really have only 3 reasonable options here:

1. Increase B+ to the 100's of Volts that the tubes you're using need.
2. Use low-voltage tubes (and suffer from their limitations and non-availability).
3. Use BJTs.